# Lock Screen inaccurately showing all-day appointments

Tags: 8.1, calendars, lock-screen

On May 11, 2014 (which *was* Mother's Day) my Lock Screen was saying that "tomorrow" would be Mother's Day. Then, on May 12 it said "today" was Mother's Day. However, when I checked my Calendar, I could clearly see that Mother's Day was May 11.

[image: Lock Screen shows Mother's Day as Monday May 12][image: Calendar says Mother's Day is on May 11]

What's going on here? How do I fix it, and prevent it from affecting other calendar events?

Some notes about the phone and its configuration:

Make/Model: Nokia Lumia 920
OS Version: 8.10.12359.845
Date+Time Setting: 24-hour clock, set automatically, (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Lock Screen "Choose an app to show detailed status": Calendar
Region: United States, English (United States)
Calendar is allowed to run in the background, but not when Battery Saver is on.

UPDATE

I tried [RIPS10's suggestion]. The reboot didn't help, but resetting the detailed item on the lock screen worked for Mother's Day. However, the problem has resurfaced today.

This doesn't just affect holidays - it appears to (at least) affect any all-day activity. I have a recurring Calendar item I set up myself for Patch Tuesdays, and on May 13 it's telling me that Patch Tuesday is "tomorrow".

[image: Lock Screen says Patch Tuesday is "Tomorrow" from May 13][image: Calendar shows Patch Tuesday is on May 13]

Comment: What time zone is your phone running in?

Comment: @RowlandShaw U.S. Eastern. However, I'm not sure that really matters. In the Lock Screen screenshot you can see the phone knows today is May 12, while in the Calendar view Mother's Day is shown on May 11. The Calendar view also shows May 12 ticked as the current date.

Comment: What region is your phone set to?

Comment: @karancan See update

Comment: It *might* be the case that the all day event is all day for a different timezone, and that was confusing it. It *might* also be a bug that could be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I might agree with that, but now the problem isn't just with holidays. Updating shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the Settings for Date+Time.

Try this

1. Settings > Date+time
2. Change Set Automatically to Off
3. Time zone > select coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
4. Adjust the time to match the current time in their location

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the phone first. If that doesn't solve the problem choose another app to show a detailed status. Refresh your lock screen by locking your phone. After that choose Calander again to show detailed status.

Comment: Reboot didn't work, but resetting the detailed status item did. How do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: More people got this problem, just a bug in the developer preview. Don't know what the actual problem is or how often people got this.

Comment: Can you provide links to other reports you're seeing?